# Tumblr video stuck processing.

Tags: tumblr, video

I had a Tumblr post published with a video uploaded to it. I replaced due to a technicality, but now it displays the "Processing replacement video" message eternally and even if when it does display the video thumbnail, when one plays the video it just shows an 'error playing video' message. How do I delete it?